# Count days between given Start date and End date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I wants to count the number of days between given start date and end date.

where start date and end date will entered by the user.
using that i have to count total days between them.

my database is as below

leave_id int
leave_start_date DateTime
leave_end_date DateTime
leave_days int

and my .cs(class) files of Model are as below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace LeaveModule.Models
{
    public class LeaveSet
    {
        public int user_id { get; set; }
        public DateTime leave_start_date { get; set; }
        public DateTime leave_end_date { get; set; }
        public string leave_description { get; set; }
        public decimal leave_days { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

2nd file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using ProjectManagementSystem.Models;

namespace LeaveModule.Models
{
    public class LeaveSetFetch
    {

        public static IList<LeaveSet> all()
        {
            IList<LeaveSet> result =
                (IList<LeaveSet>)HttpContext.Current.Session["leave"];

            if (result == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["leave"] = result =
                    (from l in new ProjectManagementSystemEntities3().leave_master
                     select new LeaveSet
                     {
                         user_id = l.user_id,
                         leave_start_date = l.leave_start_date,
                         leave_end_date = l.leave_end_date,
                         leave_description = l.leave_description,
                         leave_days = l.leave_days,
                         //   is_valid = l.is_valid,

                     }).ToList();

            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

So how can i do that in **MVC3**?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2012, 3, 3);
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2011, 3, 3);
var days = dt1.Subtract(dt2).TotalDays;
```

Bonus: [Here](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html) is a good blog from Jon Skeet about .Net's DateTime class